# Checking if any of the occurrence for IDs in list 'A' has happened after date in list 'B' for the same ID

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

Hope I can find pointer to right direction:

Table 'A' with several IDs reoccurring with different dates (arrival date_Domestic)
Table 'B' with several IDs reoccurring with different dates (arrival date_International)

I need to find IDs where in Table A on any occurrence their 'arrival date_International' was after (>) 'arrival date_Domestic' in Table B

[image]

I cant just do if date B > date A as it need to check for the particular ID, also tried  `=IF(MAX(FILTER($F$3:$F$15,$E$3:$E$15=A3))>B3,"Y","N")` but it just check against a row not taking ID in consideration.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There are 2 dates in Table A for ID 26177, one after date in Table B one before. To which to compare and why?

Comment: @user11222393 need to match with the closest one, its one to many match - looking for the closest occurrence in the other table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to filter for ID and date.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((tblA[ID]=[@ID])*(tblA[date_int]>[@[date_dom]])),"Y","N")
```

Using the new `LET`-formula might make it more readable:

```
=LET(maxDateDom,MAX(FILTER([date_dom],[ID]=[@ID])),
     maxDateInt,MAX(FILTER(tblA[date_int],tblA[ID]=[@ID])),
     maxDateInt>maxDateDom)
```

But you are inconsistent in your question regarding which date to be after which.

If you want date_int < date_dom then switch to `tblA[date_int]<[@[date_dom]` in the formula.

[image]